# No CDC generated by Kafka Debezium connector for Postgres

Tags: postgresql, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium, cdc

I succeed generating CDC in a Postgres DB.
Today, when I use same step to try to set up Kafka Debezium connector for another Postgres DB.

First I ran

POST http://localhost:8083/connectors

with body:

```
{
    "name": "postgres-kafkaconnector",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector",
        "tasks.max": "1",
        "database.hostname": "example.com",
        "database.port": "5432",
        "database.dbname": "my_db",
        "database.user": "xxx",
        "database.password": "xxx",
        "database.server.name": "postgres_server",
        "table.include.list": "public.products",
        "plugin.name": "pgoutput"
    }
}
```

which succeed without error.

Then I ran

GET http://localhost:8083/connectors/postgres-kafkaconnector/status

to check status. It returns this result without any error:

```
{
    "name": "postgres-kafkaconnector",
    "connector": {
        "state": "RUNNING",
        "worker_id": "10.xx.xx.xx:8083"
    },
    "tasks": [
        {
            "id": 0,
            "state": "RUNNING",
            "worker_id": "10.xx.xx.xx:8083"
        }
    ],
    "type": "source"
}
```

However, this time, when I updated anything in the `products` table. No CDC got generated.

Any idea? Any suggestion for helping further debug would be appreciate. Thanks!

Comment: Look at the logs? Just because status is healthy doesn't mean it's actually doing anything

Comment: Hi @OneCricketeer what logs are you referring to? Thanks!

Comment: Docker logs or the output from `connect-distributed` command that you started the server with. (The connect worker logs)

Comment: @OneCricketeer I redeployed the Kafka Debezium connector. And I checked the Kafka Connect logs, there is no error in the log..

Comment: So, you've created a new post, and looks like some records are working?

Comment: Hi @OneCricketeer [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71165403/some-rows-in-the-postgres-table-can-generate-cdc-while-others-cannot) is for a different Postgres DB which I succeed setting up using same step and works, but just has a weird issue. Not related with this question.

Comment: If it works with a different database, then sounds like a database server setup problem, not with Connector. You've not enabled some Postgres config, or installed a plugin https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/stable/connectors/postgresql.html#setting-up-postgresql

Comment: @OneCricketeer Unfortunately, I tried hard to compare the difference. However, didn't find any difference... I will report back if I find the issue!

Comment: Thanks @OneCricketeer ! It works now. And these two different issues actually are caused by same reason. I posted in the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue! It is because my Kafka Connector `postgres-kafkaconnector` was initially pointing to a DB (stage1), then I switched to another DB (stage2) by updating

```
"database.hostname": "example.com",
"database.port": "5432",
"database.dbname": "my_db",
"database.user": "xxx",
"database.password": "xxx",
```

However, they are using same configuration properties in the Kafka Connect I deployed in the very beginning:

```
config.storage.topic
offset.storage.topic
status.storage.topic
```

Since this connector with different DB config shared same above Kafka configuration properties, nd the database table schemas are same,

it became mess due to sharing same Kafka offset.

One simple way to fix is when deploying Kafka connector to test on different DBs, using different names such as `postgres-kafkaconnector-stage1` and `postgres-kafkaconnector-stage2` to avoid Kafka topic offset mess.