# Some rows in the Postgres table can generate CDC while others cannot

Tags: postgresql, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium, cdc

I have a Postgres DB with CDC setup.

I deployed the Kafka Debezium connector 1.8.0.Final for a Postgres DB by

POST http://localhost:8083/connectors

with body:

```
{
    "name": "postgres-kafkaconnector",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector",
        "tasks.max": "1",
        "database.hostname": "example.com",
        "database.port": "5432",
        "database.dbname": "my_db",
        "database.user": "xxx",
        "database.password": "xxx",
        "database.server.name": "postgres_server",
        "table.include.list": "public.products",
        "plugin.name": "pgoutput"
    }
}
```

I noticed some strange things.

In same table, when I update rows, some rows can generate CDC, but other rows cannot generate CDC.

And those rows are very similar except for `id` and `identifier` are different.

```
-- Updating this row can generate CDC
UPDATE public.products
SET identifier = 'GET /api/accounts2'
WHERE id = '90c21719-ce41-4523-8ad1-ed6b21ecfaf1';

-- Updating this row cannot generate CDC
UPDATE public.products
SET identifier = 'GET /api/notworking/accounts2'
WHERE id = '22f5ebf3-9594-493d-8aa6-649d9fbcefd2';
```

I checked my Kafka Connect container log, there is no error neither.

Any idea?

Comment: Can you provide more details about the database so someone may try to reproduce the problem? For example, your table schema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue! It is because my Kafka Connector `postgres-kafkaconnector` was initially pointing to a DB (stage1), then I switched to another DB (stage2) by updating

```
"database.hostname": "example.com",
"database.port": "5432",
"database.dbname": "my_db",
"database.user": "xxx",
"database.password": "xxx",
```

However, they are using same configuration properties in the Kafka Connect I deployed in the very beginning:

```
config.storage.topic
offset.storage.topic
status.storage.topic
```

Since this connector with different DB config shared same above Kafka configuration properties, nd the database table schemas are same,

it became mess due to sharing same Kafka offset.

One simple way to fix is when deploying Kafka connector to test on different DBs, using different names such as `postgres-kafkaconnector-stage1` and `postgres-kafkaconnector-stage2` to avoid Kafka topic offset mess.